# How we can do this in python for example when a user enter the password like this abc123g and after that the password should be this one abc***g

Tags: python-3.x

```
Pass = input ('enter a password: ')
import random
Import re
Character = []
Digit = []
for I in Len(pass):
    If re.isdigit():
       Digit [I]
    Else:
        Re.ischar():
        Character [I]
```

Comment: Do you mean `pass = re.sub( "\d", "*", pass )`?

Comment: I want to hide the digits in the password not character.

Comment: @ImranUllah How do you know the password would have any digits at all?  How do you how many of the password's characters would have digits?  In general, you shouldn't know at all what the user entered.

Comment: Yeah I mean when a user enter the password i.e it may contain 5 digits and character like this password: abcs123g37 so I wana how to hide only digits not character like this ABCs***g**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *mask* the input password by showing only the first three characters and final character, with `*` placeholders for the rest, we can try `re.sub` here:

```py
Pass = input ('enter a password: ')
Pass_Out = re.sub(r'^(.{3})(.*)(.)$', lambda x: x.group(1) + re.sub(r'.', '*', x.group(2)) + x.group(3), Pass)
print(Pass_Out)
```

Given an input of `ABC123Blah`, the above prints `ABC******h`.

Comment: His code clearly implies he wants to replace the digits with "*", not replace by position.

Comment: @TimRoberts ... and that's totally the wrong way to mask something, since a password input could be _anything_, including not having any numbers at all.

Comment: I want to hide the digits in the password not the character.

Comment: No denying it is a silly thing to do, but that's his problem statement.  Did you not see my first comment way up top?  I showed you exactly how to do this.

Comment: @TimRoberts `I showed you exactly how to do this.` ... that's great, because I am very weak with using regular expressions.  Thanks for the info.